# error in using quotation in QString

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get an input(username) from user and search for that in my sqlite to find it's password for recovery.

```
QString username = QInputDialog::getText(this, "Password Recovery", "please enter ur Username here:", QLineEdit::Normal,"myUsername", Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags(), Qt::ImhNone);

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("/home/arian_press/Qt5.7.0/Projects/APQt_chat/apt.db");

if (db.open())
{
QSqlQuery query;

QString qstr="SELECT username,password,support_email FROM users WHERE username=\""+username+"\";" ;
}
if (query.exec(qstr))
{
    QString password=query.value(1).toString();
    QString pass = "ur password is:" + password;
    Smtp *newMail  = new Smtp("arian.press2015@gmail.com",query.value(2).toString()," Your Password",pass);
    delete newMail;

    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.critical(0,"Error","ur credentials are wrong!");
    messageBox.setFixedSize(500,200);
}
else
{
qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
}
db.close();
}
else
{
qDebug() << "Failed to connect to database.";
}
```

but when i run the program, It doesn't return anything while when I open SQLite file in terminal I can get results.

**update:
U didn't mean what I said. the problem is that I can't use \" in the above code because for the query i need: SELECT username,password,support_email FROM users WHERE username="myusername"

but when I use above code it queries for SELECT username,password,support_email FROM users WHERE username=\"myusername\"
 so I can't have any results.so now how can I bring quotation marks in QString?

Comment: Sorry, but what is this code supposed to do ? You open a database and then you build a string? You cannot get anything if you don't send a query to the database.

Comment: And you can't "return anything" if you never `return` anything... Don't post incomplete fragments of code with vague wishes of what should happen, without any evidence that you tried to make it happen! Post a full, compilable sample and explain what users should do to test it. In the process of preparing that, you might realise what you missed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL uses single quotes for strings. Try:

```
QString qstr="SELECT username,password,support_email FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"';";
```

There is also a more elegant way:

```
query.prepare("SELECT username,password,support_email FROM users WHERE username = :username;");
query.bindValue(":username", username);
query.exec();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Never concatenate user input with your queries: that makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use *prepared statements*!**

Furthermore, you must use single quotation marks `'`.

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT username,password,support_email "
              "FROM users "
              "WHERE username=':username';");
query.bindValue(":username", username);
```

The `}` following your `QString qstr = ...` should be removed.